# Trying to upload image to a FileField model using REST framework or Tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Can anyone give me a step by step/ link resource on how I can upload a file from a mobile/desktop application to a Django based server using a REST API?

The server has a model with a FileField named "thumbnail". I'm able to upload other data but files seem to be a huge problem.

Note that I'm not talking about uploading using a browser/Django form but from an app through an Http request

api:

```
from models import Article

class ArticleResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
        filtering = {'title': ALL}
        authorization=Authorization()
```

independent python script I'm using to make Http Requests(mock mobile app)

```
url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/article/"

data={
    'title':'Tastypie',
    'body':'First Restful client',
    'pub_date':'05/02/2015',
    }
files=  {'thumbnail': open('django.png', 'rb')}
headers =  {'content-type': 'image/png'}
print requests.post(url, files=files)
```

model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

**EDIT:**

This worked:

api:

```
class MultipartResource(object):
        def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
            if not format:
                 format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
            if format =='application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                return request.POST
            if format.startswith('multipart'):
                data = request.POST.copy()
                photo = Article()
                photo.thumbnail = request.FILES['thumbnail']
                photo.title = request.POST.get('title')
                photo.body=request.POST.get('body')
                photo.pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date')
                photo.save()
                # ... etc
                return data
            return super(ArticleResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

        # overriding the save method to prevent the object getting saved twice 
        def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
             pass


class ArticleResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
        filtering = {'title': ALL}
        authorization=Authorization()
```

Http Request Python script:

```
url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/article/"

data={
    'title':'Tastypie',
    'body':'First Restful client',
    'pub_date':'2015-02-05',
    }
files=  {'thumbnail': open('django.png', 'rb')}

print requests.post(url, data=data, files=files).text
```

Comment: What happens when you run your script? Or better yet, what happens when you use `curl`, does the rest of the data save and not the file? Or does it all error?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Whenever I run the script like this:`headers =  {'content-type': 'application/json'}
print requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers).text`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Whenever I run the script like this:`headers =  {'content-type': 'application/json'}
> print requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers).text` It runs fine but the minute I edit it to add files it gives a 500 error with: "error_message": "The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on your Serializer."

Comment: Glad it worked. +1 for posting your solution to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tastypie doens't have any good way to save binary files. I'd try something like this:

```
class ArticleResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
        filtering = {'title': ALL}
        authorization=Authorization()    

    # save the photo
        def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
            if not format:
                format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')

            if format.startswith('multipart'):
                data = request.POST.copy()
                photo = Article()
                photo.thumbnail = request.FILES['thumbnail']
                photo.title = request.POST.get('title')
                # ... etc
                return data
            return super(ArticleResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

        # overriding the save method to prevent the object getting saved twice 
        def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
            pass
```

Comment: Still not working, whenever I use `print requests.post(url, data=data, files=files,headers=headers).text` I get a message saying `"error_message": "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 409: invalid start byte. You passed in '--da8f68c94da44747ae6980923316c7ec\\r\\nContent-Disposition: form-data` but when I use `requests.post(url, data=data, files=files).text` I get `{"error_message": "The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`

Comment: Why would you do that? I don't get it.

Comment: It actually worked after some minor edits like putting the deserialize functions in their own class. Thanks!